# Which sins are specifically punished with earthquake?

Tags: halacha, sin, reward-punishment, natural-phenomenon

There were/are earthquakes in many countries in the world in the past few days.

If earthquake is a form punishment from Hashem, then which sins are punished by such?

I/We can use the answer to specifically pray for Teshuvah.

"Why assume that specific natural disasters correspond to particular sins?"

There are passages in the TaNaKH about famine or drought, etc., being associated with sins, such as Amos 4:7-8

וְגַם אָנֹכִי מָנַעְתִּי מִכֶּם אֶת-הַגֶּשֶׁם, בְּעוֹד שְׁלֹשָׁה חֳדָשִׁים לַקָּצִיר, וְהִמְטַרְתִּי עַל-עִיר אֶחָת, וְעַל-עִיר אַחַת לֹא אַמְטִיר; חֶלְקָה אַחַת תִּמָּטֵר, וְחֶלְקָה אֲשֶׁר-לֹא-תַמְטִיר עָלֶיהָ תִּיבָשׁ.

וְנָעוּ שְׁתַּיִם שָׁלֹשׁ עָרִים אֶל-עִיר אַחַת, לִשְׁתּוֹת מַיִם--וְלֹא יִשְׂבָּעוּ; וְלֹא-שַׁבְתֶּם עָדַי, נְאֻם-יְהוָה.

I was thinking that perhaps Earthquake is probably in the same line of idea.

Here is a discussion at Mi Yodea along a similar line:

[Which sins are specifically punished with drought?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/82949/which-sins-are-specifically-punished-with-drought)

Comment: _There are passages in the TaNaKH_ Where? Do they indicate that such an occurrence can be a punishment for a particular sin (which doesn't preclude it being a punishment for some other sin) or do they indicate that they are specifically punishments for particular sins?

Comment: @mevaqesh I think Amos 4:7-8 answers your question that Hashem withholds rain, because we do not do Teshuvah. Now whether such "preclude it being a punishment for some other sin", I do not know.

Answer (score 2):

There is a reference in [Yerushalmi Brachot, 64a chapter 9, halacha 2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r1109.htm) said in the name of Rabbi Acha that associates males homosexual practice with earthquakes.

> תני בר קפרא מתריעין על הזועות.  שמואל אמר אין עבר ההן זיקא בכסיל מחריב העולם.  מתיבון לשמואל ואנן חמין ליה עבר אמר להון לית איפשר או לעיל מינה או לרע מינה.  שמואל אמר חכים אנא בשקקי שמיא כשקקי נהרדעי קרתי.  בר מן ההן זיקא לית אנא ידע מה הוא.  וכי שמואל עלה לשמים אלא על שם (איוב לח) מי יספר שחקים בחכמה.  אליהו ז"ל שאל לר' נהוריי מפני מה באין זועות לעולם אמר ליה בעון תרומה ומעשרות.  כתוב אחד אומר (דברים יא) תמיד עיני ה' אלהיך בה וכתוב אחד (תהילים קד) המביט לארץ ותרעד יגע בהרים ויעשנו.  הא כיצד יתקיימו שני כתובין הללו בשעה שישראל עושין רצונו של מקום ומוציאין מעשרותיהן כתיקונן תמיד עיני ה' אלהיך בה מראשית השנה ועד אחרית השנה ואינה ניזוקת כלום.  בשעה שאין ישראל עושין רצונו של מקום ואינן מוציאין מעשרותיהן כתיקונן המביט לארץ ותרעד.  אמר ליה בני חייך כך היא סברא דמילתא.  אבל כך עיקרו של דבר אלא בשעה שהקב"ה מביט בבתי תיטריות ובבתי קרקסיות יושבות בטח ושאנן ושלוה ובית מקדשו חרב הוא אפילון לעולמו להחריבו.  הה"ד (ירמיהו כה) שאוג ישאג על נוהו.  בשביל נויהו.  **אמר ר' אחא בעון משכב זכר.  אמר הקב"ה אתה זיעזעתה איברך על דבר שאינו שלך.  חייך שאני מזעזע עולמי על אותו האיש.**  ורבנן אמרו מפני המחלוקת.  (זכריה יד) ונסתם גיא הרי כי יגיע גיא הרים אל אצל.  אמר רבי שמואל אין רעש אלא הפסק מלכות.  כמה דאת אמר (ישעיהו יג) ותרעש הארץ ותחל.  מפני מה (שם) כי קמה על בבל מחשבות ה'.  אליהו ז"ל שאל לר' נהוריי מפני מה ברא הקב"ה שקצים ורמשים בעולמו.  אמר לו לצורך נבראו בשעה שהבריות חוטאין הוא מביט בהן ואמר מה אלו שאין בהן צורך הרי אני מקיימן אלו שיש בהן צורך לכ"ש אמר ליה עוד הן יש בהן צורך זבוב לצירעה פשפש לעלוקתה נחש לחפפית שבלון לחזיות סממית לעקרב:  פיסקא על הברקים וכו' רבי ירמיה ורבי זעירא בשם רב חסדאי דיו פעם אחת בכל היום.  אמר רבי יוסי מה אנן קיימין אם בטורדין דיו

Comment: Thanks. So that we will not be accused of cherry picking a particular sin and directly associating it with earthquakes, would you kindly list here in English (from the above source) all the listed possible sins that could effect an earthquake? And then I would like to repeat mevaqesh's question/comment: "Do they indicate that such an occurrence can be a punishment for a particular sin (which doesn't preclude it being a punishment for some other sin) or do they indicate that they are specifically punishments for particular sins?"

Comment: If the above is true, with the new laws in this country, it's a wonder that we don't have earthquakes every day here...big ones

Comment: @Gary If judgement were one dimensional and simple, dealing with only a single subject, then what you say would be be correct. But Heavenly judgement is very complex and assesses all aspects. So even though you may see some detail that looks like it deserves 'punishment', in the total picture, judgement may be very different. That is why we refer to G-d as the 'Judge of Truth' or the 'True Judge'.

Comment: @YaacovDeane - "The generation of the Flood was not wiped out until they wrote marriage documents for the union of a man to a male.."  Keep watching the seismographs...